# Java Frameworks that support Entity-Attribute-Value Models

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, entity-attribute-value

I am interested in developing a portal-based application that works with [EAV models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model) and would like to know if there are any Java frameworks that aid in this type of development?

salesforce.com uses EAV and currently has twenty tables. The framework I seek should allow it to be configurable to different EAV implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) is a more modern RDF API compared to Jena. [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/) can be seen as a variant of the EAV model.

> The framework I seek should allow it
>   to be configurable to different EAV
>   implementations

Both Jena and Sesame are available as API layers for many RDF storage engines.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how RDF relates to EAV?

Comment: In RDF the Entity-Attribute-Value translates to Subject-Predicate-Object, where Subjects and Predicates are resources and objects are either resources or literals. So you can describe Predicates as well via Subject-Predicate-Object statements. RDF is more formal than EAV. In addition to this you get multiple serialization formats, schemas/ontologies for additional constraints and semantics and a query language (SPARQL).

Answer (score 0):

The [Jena library](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) is a standard for handling a set of RDF statements (Resource/Property/Object).

Other RDF engine: http://mulgara.org/, http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuoso/...

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how RDF relates to EAV?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your custom EAV with Hibernate using Map element mapping (example in Groovy):

```
@Entity
public class FooEntity {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  long id;


  @CollectionOfElements
  Map<String,String> propz;   

}
```