# Dynamic fields in JSF beans

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf

I want to let my client create his own fields and bean in the CMS dynamically.

As well, once he creates a form, I need to create an Hibernate Entity that could be saved to the database.

Is there a way to do it?

I am using JSF2 and Hibernate 3

With recompiling and without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Creating tables and entities dynamically is IMO not a good idea. Hibernate is not really made for that and generating entities is only a **small part** of the problem. You would have to add them to the configuration, rebuild a session factory, update the model. And what about subsequent restarts of the application?</strike> Not recommended, just forget this approach...

Another option would be to use an [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model. This is something many CMS are doing. I've never implemented this with Hibernate but it's doable (and has already been done). Here are some resources:

- [Adding new persistable classes at runtime](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=928399)
- [[hibernate-dev] dynamic entities](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2007-April/001831.html) (has some sources attached)

But to be honest, I wouldn't implement my own CMS but rather reuse an existing one. [One Hippo](http://www.onehippo.com/) seems to be a candidate.

#### See also

- [The CCK buzz (Content Creation Kit) and the EAV problem](http://sankuru.biz/fr/blog/8-joomla-configuration-issues/35-the-cck-buzz-content-creation-kit-and-the-eav-problem.html)

#### Related questions

- [Entity Attribute Value Database vs. strict Relational Model Ecommerce question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question)
- [Approach to generic database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310630/approach-to-generic-database-design)
- [How do you build extensible data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945062/how-do-you-build-extensible-data-model)
- [I am looking for something similar to the drupal CCK, but in Java (in a Java CMS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054508/i-am-looking-for-something-similar-to-the-drupal-cck-but-in-java-in-a-java-cms)
- [Java Frameworks that support Entity-Attribute-Value Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205793/java-frameworks-that-support-entity-attribute-value-models)
- [Implementing EAV pattern with Hibernate for User -> Settings relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646035/implementing-eav-pattern-with-hibernate-for-user-settings-relationship)

Comment: Thank you. My question is, once we have already used Hibernate + Hibernate Search, do you think that it worth while to switch to MyBatis or another O/R Mapping?

Comment: @Odelya: Well, I guess not. Actually, I rewrote almost entirely my answer since Hibernate has already been used to implement an EAV approach (so regardless of my opinion, this is doable). But, as I wrote, I wouldn't write yet another CMS and reuse an existing one offering the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you.
The ability to add/remove fields is only one small part of my application. So I guess that I will have to integrate my code

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be using a `List<String>` for the field names and a `Map<String, Object>` for the field values. Maps can be accessed in EL using dynamic keys like so:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.fieldnames}" var="fieldname">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.fieldvalues[fieldname]}" /><br />
</ui:repeat>
```

A completely different alternative is to autogenerate classes using tools like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)/[Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) and creating database tables on the fly. But that's a lot more work.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer.

Let's say that my user wants to create a new object named: Order with custom fields: name, time, username.

How can I create a completely new bean ? I know that I can iterate over the results, but how can I create a new bean based on DB information as well as a Hibernate object?

Comment: Then go for the last suggestion. Follow the links, they contains tutorials. Not meant to be harsh, but given your knowledge shown as far, this is going to be a long journey. That's why I suggested an easy and more abstract solution as well as 1st suggestion.

Comment: After a second thought, aren't you actually reinventing/homegrowing a CMS? I'd rather look for existing CMS'es as Pascal mentioned. Hippo, Alfresco, Nuxeo, Liferay, etc.